# estimate covariance of a matrix

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, im implementing regularized particle filter. My particle has coordinate x,y,z. All particles would make up a matrix n by 3 matrix . i wonder is there any existing code to find covariance matrix of a matrix in c++ somewhere in ros . This is easily done by matlab but c++ is too complicated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221909/estimate-covariance-of-a-matrix/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unaware of a "ROS" way of doing this, but if you are using C++, I'd recommend using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/). It is easily installed and used extensively by many ROS packages. If you're using a ROS Indigo or Jade, you'll need to depend on the [cmake_modules](http://wiki.ros.org/cmake_modules) package to get catkin to build your code (see [these instructions](https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/blob/0.3-devel/README.md#usage)).

If you're using Eigen, there are easy ways to calculate covariance using built-in Eigen matrix functions. For a few examples, see [this Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138634/eigen-is-there-an-inbuilt-way-to-calculate-sample-covariance).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-12-03**:
thanks so much, the library is good but it is still so slow as the matrix is big, is there anyway to speed it up

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-12-04**:
@dmngu9 so you want to say that it is much slower in Eigen than in Matlab? sounds suspicious